# Explicit value must be specified when initialized replication from backup

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a big SQL Server database that I wan to replicate, I have try using snapshots but it takes so much time so I decided to initialized replication with a backup instead. The works for a period of time but at some point starts giving me this error:

> Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'DocumentDetail' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column

The weird thing is that the table `DocumentDetail` is not in the Publication's database.

I have delete the subscriber and publisher and recreate them and after sometime it happen again.

**Subscription on Publisher**

```sql
EXEC sp_addsubscription
    @publication = N'Publication', 
    @subscriber = N'SUBSCRIBER', 
    @destination_db = N'ACCLTD', 
    @sync_type = N'initialize with backup', 
    @backupdevicetype='Disk', 
    @backupdevicename='\\path\of\backup.bak',
    @subscription_type = N'pull',
    @update_mode = N'read only'
GO
```

**On Subscriber**

```sql
EXEC sp_addpullsubscription
    @publisher = N'VXACCPAC2', 
    @publication = N'Publication', 
    @publisher_db = N'DATABASE', 
    @independent_agent = N'True', 
    @subscription_type = N'pull', 
    @description = N'', 
    @update_mode = N'read only', 
    @immediate_sync = 0
GO
```

**Add the Pull Subscription Agent**

```sql
EXEC sp_addpullsubscription_agent
    @publisher = N'DATABASE_SERVER', 
    @publisher_db = N'DATABASE', 
    @publication = N'Publication', 
    @distributor = N'DISTRIBUTOR', 
    @distributor_security_mode = 1, 
    @distributor_login = N'domain\username', 
    @distributor_password = N'password', 
    @enabled_for_syncmgr = N'False', 
    @frequency_type = 64, 
    @frequency_interval = 0, 
    @frequency_relative_interval = 0, 
    @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0, 
    @frequency_subday = 0, 
    @frequency_subday_interval = 0, 
    @active_start_time_of_day = 0, 
    @active_end_time_of_day = 235959, 
    @active_start_date = 20190827, 
    @active_end_date = 99991231, 
    @alt_snapshot_folder = N'', 
    @working_directory = N'',
    @use_ftp = N'False', 
    @job_login = N'domain\username', 
    @job_password = N'password', 
    @publication_type = 0
GO
```

Comment: Where are you seeing that error?  Do you perhaps have a non-"NOT FOR REPLICATION" trigger on a subscriber table?

Comment: It was a trigger on the subscriber, thank you David!